# Accessing hidden folder in Sublime & IDE editors

Tags: encryption, phpstorm, directory, sublimetext3, hidden-files

How can I not access or even view the folder with a password in editors? Because right now the folder has a password and it was hidden in the list of directories but in my editor I can see it and I don't want that.

Comment: How exactly was a folder hidden? Which operating system? Was it a 3rd party tool?

Comment: I have a laravel project and our school also want a copy of the system. I want to hide the folder that contains my codes. The folder that was hidden is the "app" and I'm using Windows 10, no 3rd party tool.

Comment: Why? What for? In any case: you can apply hidden/system file attributes using `attrib` DOS command e.g. `attrib +S +H C:\MyProjects\app`. It's not really "a protection" -- will not prevent files from being read/executed if full path is known .. but may hide from inexperienced eyes.